# Difference between 0+0+0+0...infinite times and 0 multiplied by infinity.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity, indeterminate-forms

The measure/size of set I came across that the measure of a set that is formed by intersection of countably infinite disjoint sets of measure 0 each, will be the sum of the measures of all the sets = 0+0+0+0+...(infinite terms). This can be calculated by taking the limit of the sequence of  partial sums. The sequence of partial sums will be 0,0,0,... . So, from the limit of the sequence of partial sums, 0+0+0+0+... = 0.
My doubt is that shouldn't 0+0+0+... = 0.$\infty$ and therefore indeterminate?

Edit 1: I'm not concerned with the limit in this case, but the actual value of 0+0+0+... and how is it different from 0.$\infty$.

Edit 2: How appropriate is it to use the limit of a function at a point instead of the function value at that point? The function need not be smooth or continuous.

Comment: [Multiplication ain't no repeated addition.](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_06_08.html)

Comment: And if you are taking limits, then there is no indeterminate form.  The limit is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} 0 = \lim_{n\to \infty} 0\cdot n = \lim_{n\to\infty} 0 = 0. $$

Comment: Note that what is "indeterminate" is applying $(\lim f)\lim g=\lim(fg)$, when $\lim f=0$ and $\lim g=\infty$ and no other information of $f$ and $g$ is at hand. However, the case $f=0$ is not indeterminate.

Comment: Also, don't read that title "Multiplication ain't no repeated addition" strictly. It is an exaggeration, a clickbait title. The content has a point, but it is misguided in not being the whole story.  Multiplication is many things, can be interpreted and extended in many ways, and one of those is indeed repeated addition.

Comment: I would say that $0\cdot\infty$ is not technically indeterminate, but an abbreviation for what we do with limits.  If you actually do the multiplication, the result is 0.  However, with limits, neither part (usually) actually attains zero or infinity, so it is not technically $0\cdot\infty$ but small$\cdot$large, and the result is based on the specifics of the formulas.

Comment: Regarding your edit, how do you define $0+0+0+\dotsb$, if not as a limit?

Comment: @johnnyb Your comment is incorrect. The expression is definitely indeterminate and not equal to zero. Some expressions involving $\infty$ can (if we consider it legal) be easily evaluated as if they were in real numbers, eg $1/\infty=0$ or $\infty+\infty=\infty$. These cases have a consistent result whether we consider them as expressions where $\infty$ is a number or as shorthands for limits (ie, $1/f\to0$ where $f\to\infty$). But indeterminate forms such as $0\times\infty$ do not. We could have $(1/x)\times(x)\to1$ or $(1/x)\times(x^2)\to\infty$ etc. The result is indeterminate.

Comment: @Jam In this context, I think that johnnyb is more correct than you are.  There are ways of making sense of an arithmetic of infinities (e.g. the hyperreal numbers), but I don't think that these are relevant to the discussion *here*, where a student is struggling with some more basic concepts.  Introducing a new number system is, I think, likely to confuse, rather than enlighten.

Comment: @Jam - $1/\infty \neq 0$, the *limit* is zero.  If you are dealing with a number system that includes infinities explicitly (like the hyperreal system), then, for a hyperreal number $\omega$, $1/\omega$ is just an infinitesimal, but **still** not zero. You can read $0 \cdot \infty$ as either "I have zero infinities" or "I have an infinite number of zeroes", and both of them yield the same thing - zero. However, if you have an infinite number of infinitesimals, and you aren't any more specific than that, **then** your result is indeterminate (however, in the hyperreals, you can get an answer).

Comment: @johnnyb Let me rephrase. I agree with most of your comment except for "If you actually do the multiplication, the result is 0.". My point is that even if you do allow direct computation (I was considering with the [extended reals](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffinelyExtendedRealNumbers.html) and I agree with Xander is more confusing than beneficial), you don't get a simple "$\ldots=0$". As you noted, $0\times \infty$, as a limit of a product of functions could equal $0,\infty$ or a constant depending on the orders. So $0\times\infty$ *is* "indeterminate" (ie lacks a catch-all evaluation).

Answer (score 4):

You basically answered your question. There are no ambiguous terms in math like adding something infinite amount of times. You have to **define** what you mean by infinity. In this case, the infinite sum is just a limit of partial sums, **by definition**. So it has to be $0$.

Comment: I just have the set A which is union of countably infinite disjoint sets whose measure is zero. Now to find the measure of A, i can add the measure of all sets which will give me 0+0+0+... To evaluate this sum, I define a sequence of partial sum which will be 0,0,0,... The limit of this sequence will give me the required sum which will be 0. I'm asking why is 0+0+0+...not indeterminate and how is it different from 0.$\infty$

Comment: @theDemid since the measure is countably additive, this amounts to finding $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \mu (A_i) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} 0 =  \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Neither make sense as arithmetic expressions (no infinite number of terms, $\infty$ is not a number). In that sense they are "the same".

In analysis, an "infinite sum" is understood as a limit:
$$
\sum_{k \ge 1} a_k = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{1 \le k \le N} a_k
$$
so your first sum would be $0$. But again, $\infty$ is not a number, so $0 \cdot \infty$ makes no sense. Closest would be some limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \cdot g(x)
$$
where $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$.
But in that case the limit could be anything at all, er even don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

When you say the sum $0+0 + . . . + 0$, I assume you're talking about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0$. Since infinite summation is defined in terms of limits, the indeterminate form $0 \cdot \infty$ doesn't come up.

In other words, the reason that $0 \cdot \infty$ is indeterminate is that $\lim_{h\to\infty}h\cdot0\neq\lim_{h\to0}\infty\cdot h$. If we defined $0\cdot\infty$ as anything *but* indeterminate, it would imply that $\pm\infty=0$, since the first limit is zero and the second is (negative) infinity.

Since the infinite sum is equal to the first limit, it unambiguously comes out to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\boldsymbol{0\cdot\infty}$

There is no real number $\infty$, so the product $0\cdot\infty$ has no meaning as a real number. When we talk about $0\cdot\infty$ being indeterminate, we are talking about
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot b_n\tag1
$$
where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=\infty$.

As mentioned earlier, there is no real number $\infty$. What we mean by $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=\infty$ is that for any $M\gt0$, there is an $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$, we have $b_n\ge M$; that is, $b_n$ can be made as large as one wants by choosing $n$ large enough.

To see why this is called indeterminate, for any real $r$, consider the sequences
$$
a_n=\frac rn\quad\text{and}\quad b_n=n\tag2
$$
In each of these cases, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot b_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}r=r\tag3
$$
That is, knowing $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=\infty$ does not tell us what $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot b_n$ is.

In conclusion, $0\cdot\infty$ is shorthand for a class of limit problems.

---

$\boldsymbol{0+0+0+0+\ldots}$

This can be written as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n0=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0\tag4
$$
This is one particular series limit.